# Select rows conditionally and insert into another table conditionally

Tags: t-sql

How to insert into table 2 all field values of a row from table A, where all values in a column A in table 1 that satisfy a condition on column B of table 1 ,but do not exist in table 2.How to frame a query using not exists?

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Teachermast (
  teacher_code,
  teacher_name,
  designation,
  dept_code,
  contact_no,
  email,
  address,
  dob,
  PASSWORD
) 
SELECT 
  userId,
  username,
  designation,
  dept,
  contact_no,
  email,
  address,
  dob,
  PASSWORD 
FROM
  UserMast 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 
    userId 
  FROM
    UserMast 
  WHERE usertype = '3')
```

but this doesnt seem to work. 
Kindly help.

Comment: please show some sample data in both the tables and show expected output

Comment: table 1: (userId,username,usertype,password,contact_no,email,faxno,address,created_date,updated_date,status,gender,dob,lasttimelogin,login_time,logout_time,designation,dept,email_pass)T0003 Ankita 3 12345 9858585245 anki@gmail.com  201 l block noida sec 25 NULL NULL NULL Female 11/09/1990 NULL NULL NULL Teacher EC NULL
T0004 Ribha 3 12345 9512365423 sharma@gmail.com NULL 221 dwarka sec 10 NULL NULL NULL Female 12/02/1989 NULL NULL NULL Teacher EC NULL

Comment: table 2: (teacher_code,teacher_name,designation,dept_code,contact_no,email,address,dob,password)  
T0002 Tanvi Teacher NULL CS NULL NULL 9632569856 tan123@gmail.com 298 mayur vihar ph 1 29/06/1990 NULL 12345
T0003 Ankita Teacher NULL EC NULL NULL 9858585245 anki@gmail.com 201 l block noida sec 25 11/09/1990 NULL 12345

Comment: now i want record T0004 from table 1 in table 2 as its usertype= '3'

Comment: @AnitaMathew if the answer below has worked, please mark it as the accepted answer by checking the checkmark under the vote down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a MERGE

```
create table users
(
    userId varchar(50),
    username varchar(50),
    usertype int,
    password varchar(50),
    contact_no varchar(50),
    email varchar(50),
    faxno varchar(50),
    address varchar(50),
    created_date date,
    updated_date date,
    status varchar(50),
    gender varchar(50),
    dob date,
    lasttimelogin datetime,
    login_time datetime,
    logoutt_time datetime,
    designation varchar(50),
    dept varchar(50),
    email_pass varchar(50)
)
insert into users values('T0003','Ankita',3,'12345','9858‌​585245','anki@gmail.com','201','l block noid sec 25',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Female','11/09/1990',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Teacher','EC',NULL); 
insert into users values('T0004','Ribha',3,'12345','9512365423','sharma@gmail.com',NULL,'221 dwarka sec 10',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Female','12/02/1989',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Teacher','EC',NULL);

create table teachers
(
    teacher_code varchar(50),
    teacher_name varchar(50),
    designation varchar(50),
    dept_code varchar(50),
    contact_no varchar(50),
    email varchar(50),
    address varchar(50),
    dob date,
    password varchar(50)
) 
insert into teachers values('T0002','Tanvi','Teacher','CS','9632569856','tan123@gmai‌​l.com','298 mayur vihar ph 1','29/06/1990','12345');
insert into teachers values('T0003','Ankita','Teacher','EC','9858585245','anki@gmail‌​.com','201 l block noida sec 25','11/09/1990','12345');

merge teachers as target
using (select userid, username, designation, dept, contact_no, email, address, dob, password from users where usertype = 3) 
as source(userid, username, designation, dept, contact_no, email, address, dob, password)
    on target.teacher_code = source.userid
when not matched by target then
    insert (teacher_code, teacher_name, designation, dept_code, contact_no, email, address, dob, password)
    values (source.userid, source.username, source.designation, source.dept, source.contact_no, source.email, source.address, source.dob, source.password);

select * from teachers
```

However, I think there are issues with your database design. With your current model, you could have, for example, a different address (or password!) for Ankita in table1 compared to table2. And if you change any of that information you would have to change it in both places.

Could you, for example, just insert everyone into "users" and have "teachers" be a view

```
select {columns} from users where usertype = 3
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
SELECT 
    t.userId,
    t.username,
    t.designation,
    t.dept,
    t.contact_no,
    t.email,
    t.address,
    t.dob,
    t.PASSWORD 
FROM Teachermast as  t
LEFT join UserMast as u on t.userId = u.teacher_code
WHERE t.usertype = '3' and u.teacher_code is null
```

Comment: usertype is int and teacher_code is nvarchar so it gives Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'T0002' to data type int

Comment: it gives the already existing ones i.e T0002 and T0003. i need T0004 to be added to the table.